# Assign Unicode character to a char

Tags: c, gcc, ascii

I want to do the following assignment:

```
char complete = '█', blank='░';
```

But I got the following warning (I'm using the latest version of gcc):

```
trabalho3.c: In function ‘entrar’:
trabalho3.c:243:9: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   char complete = '█', blank='░';
                    ^
trabalho3.c:243:3: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
   char complete = '█', blank='░';
                    ^
trabalho3.c:244:23: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   char complete = '█', blank='░';
                             ^
trabalho3.c:244:17: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
   char complete = '█', blank='░';
                             ^
```

How can I do this assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copy those lines from the posting and echo the result through a hex dump program, the output is:

```
0x0000: 63 68 61 72 20 63 6F 6D 70 6C 65 74 65 20 3D 20   char complete = 
0x0010: 27 E2 96 88 27 2C 20 62 6C 61 6E 6B 3D 27 E2 96   '...', blank='..
0x0020: 91 27 3B 0A                                       .';.
0x0024:
```

And when I run it through a UTF-8 decoder, the two block characters are identified as:

```
0xE2 0x96 0x88 = U+2588 (FULL BLOCK)
0xE2 0x96 0x91 = U+2591 (LIGHT SHADE)
```

And if the characters are indeed 3-bytes long, trying to store all three bytes into a single character is going to cause problems.

You need to validate these observations; there is a lot of potential for the data being filtered between your system and mine.  However, the chances are that if you take a look at the source code using similar tools, you will find that the characters are either UTF-8 or UFT-16 encoded, and neither of these will fit into a single byte.  If you think they are characters in a single-byte code set (CP-1252 or something similar, perhaps), you should show the hex dump for the line of code containing the initializations, and identify the platform and code set you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can store those characters as:

- a UTF-8 string, `const unsigned char complete[] = u8"█";`
- a wide character defined in `<wchar.h>`, `const wchar_t complete = L'█';`
- a UTF-32 character defined in `<uchar.h>`, `const char32_t complete = U'█';`
- a UTF-16 character, although this is generally a bad idea.

Use UTF-8 when you can, something else when you have to.  The 32-bit type is the only one that guarantees fixed width.  There are functions in the standard library to read and write wide-character strings, and in many locales, you can read and write UTF-8 strings just like ASCII once you call `setlocale()` or convert them to wide characters with `mbstowcs()`.